# Как передать IP адрес сервера, а не мой личный, на обработчик на другом сайте через веб форму?

Tags: php, сервер, post, ip

Задача передать POST переменные на другой сайт. На другом сайте должны прочитать IP адрес сервера на котором лежит форма с которой осуществляется POST запрос. То есть в какой бы точке мира я не находился бы, обработчик должен считывать IP адрес сервера, а не мой личный IP.
Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать или в каком направлении думать. Спасибо.

Пример формы:

```
<form action="https://paymentgateway.com/payment/" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?=$params['action']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="client_key" value="<?=$params['client_key']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?=$params['order_id']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="order_amount" value="<?=$params['order_amount']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="order_currency" value="<?=$params['order_currency']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="order_description" value="<?=$params['order_description']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="card_token" value="<?=$card_token?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: "IP адрес сервера на котором лежит форма". Это бессмысленная фраза.  
Формы не лежат на серверах. Формы лежат в браузере.

Comment: Однако, важное уточнение... А код формы где лежит?

Answer (score 0):

> Как передать IP адрес сервера, а не мой личный, на обработчик на другом сайте через веб форму?

Никак.

> в каком направлении думать.

Думать в направлении того, [где форма, а где сервер](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke).

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, отправка переменных через cURL решила задачу.